# How does variable a here has local-scope and its also its always returning window object (pointing via this keyword)

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I asked a question regarding following code:

`var b = function a(){}; b();`

**Refernece:** [Why no error in writing wrong code in JS (wrong way of writing and executing a function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67732504/why-no-error-in-writing-wrong-code-in-js-wrong-way-of-writing-and-executing-a-f?noredirect=1#comment119721310_67732504)

I said the following code should give error as this is invalid code. Functions have only 2 ways of defining - `function a(){}` OR `var a = function(){}`. So code above is invalid and should give error.

A friend replied that code above is valid, and `a` has local-scope. Now, I tried various code, but `a` always returns Global scope. If he said, that `a has local-scope` is true, then how to find that local scope, as `this keyword` should and always return local-scope or point to some object in that case.

The issue is it always returns `window-object`, so then is He (my Friend) is wrong. Please, explain or help!!

**I tried:**

`var b = function a(){console.log(this);} b();`

`var b = (function a(){console.log(this);})();`

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if i understand your question. Are you asking why `this` inside the function refers to the global `window` object?

Comment: @Yousaf - yes, if it is local to the function itself named.

Comment: I think you are confusing `this` with the [named function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#named_function_expression). `a` is the name of the function and it is only available inside the function body whereas the value of `this` inside this function depends on how you call it. Since you are invoking it as a function, in non-strict mode, `this` will refer to the global `window` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two completely independent concepts here:

- What `this` refers to inside the function
- The scope in which the identifier `a` can be referenced

You are correct in that `this` refers to the window when a plain, unbound, non-arrow function which is not part of an object is called like `b()`.

Your friend is correct in that the identifier `a` is only referenceable inside the function - it's not a global variable, it's local to the function. See:

```js
console.log(typeof a);
var b = function a() {
  console.log(typeof a);
}
b();
```

Comment: Hi, by same logic `var c = d; console.log(d);` gives error for d which is fine. But then, `var c = d = 10; console.log(d);` gives 10 for d. Why? It should also throw error for `d`, as d is right-hand side of c; How does assigment and scope for `d` works in RAM now? Does this mean whatever is right-handed most -- will not be assigned memory, rest all will be assigned? How does d in second case --now magically comes to `global-scope`?

Comment: In the second code in the comment, you're implicitly creating a global variable with `d = 10` on the right-hand side - that runs first, before the assignment result is also assigned to `c`. In the first code, you reference `d` when no such variable exists. The assignment operator's precedence is right-to-left.

Comment: Ok, so magic happened only due to "=" (assignment operator) that created global-variable for `d`? Means if I write `function alpha(){ var e = d = c = b = a = 99 }`, so `d, c, b, a` will have global-scope, and since, I used var infront of e, so `e` only, will have local-scope?

Comment: @Deadpool yes, that is correct. Everything to the right of the first `=` is part of the *initialization expression* for the local variable `a`. Unless those variables involved in that expression are declared somewhere, they will be implicit globals. Things might be less confusing for you if you'd start using "strict" mode.